# How to subset a data frame for rows which match one criteria in any of a group of columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

In R, I have a data frame (`H1`) with two columns to name each row, 89 columns with numerical data and final column with row means (I have 1000s of rows).

I need to select the rows in which any of my numerical columns are >15 for example. I can do this if I just want to select the rows by one column:

```
H1<-H2[H2[,3]>15,]
```

But not for any of all 89 columns. I tried-

```
H1<-H2[H2[,3:91]>15,]
```

but this just returns a load of NAs.

Comment: Are you using R? If so, please use the "data.frame" tag. If not, please clarify what language/program you're doing this in.

Comment: Thank you, changes above

Answer (score 1):

Using data.table (data.frame extension):

```
library(data.table)
setDT(H1)
H1[, i := any(unlist(lapply(.SD, function(x) x>15))), seq_len(nrow(H1)), .SDcols=3:92
    ][i==TRUE
      ][,i:=NULL]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowSums` in base R to compute a logical index and then subset the data by that index. Here's an example:

```
set.seed(123)
DF <- data.frame(id = sample(letters[1:3], 20, TRUE), 
                 matrix(sample(1:25, 100, TRUE), ncol = 5))
```

Now compute the index:

```
idx <- rowSums(DF[2:6] > 15) >= 1L
```

And use it to subset the data:

```
DF[idx, ]
```

Or both steps at once:

```
DF[rowSums(DF[2:6] > 15) >= 1L, ]
```

Here, I used columns 2:6. In your data you can replace that by 3:92 or what you require.